# app is not stopping at "gets" - is my online interpreter forcing a timeout?

Tags: ruby

While starting an assignment (Towers of Hanoi), I leave my code in a very basic state while I ponder the logic of how to continue.

```
while arr3.count < 6
    puts "Move ring FROM which tower?"
    from = gets.chomp
    puts "Move ring TO which tower?"
    to = gets.chomp
end
```

Before I can start building the rest of the app, however, **gets** seems to fall through without any input from me, and the second **puts** displays on the screen. This continues looping every, say, 30 seconds or so. Should I assume this is a feature of online interpreters (like codeacademy labs)?

Now I'm distracted from continuing the assignment and have to find a better place to do my code.

I'm installing Aptana (based on some advice on this forum) to see if I can get a better environment to do my assignments. Or do most people use a text editor then run their .rb file through the windows console window?

Thx

Comment: Perhaps gets (STDIN) it not bound to a blocking stream? Connect it to a useful source as required (that blocks as required).

Comment: Am doing that, while waiting for Aptana to download.

Comment: Side note: try to find meaningful names for variables instead of numbering them `arr1`, `arr2`, … Other developers (including your future self) will thank you for this :-)

Comment: I would start using a text editor and getting used to running/debugging from the command line as soon as you can. You will have to do so soon enough. For very quick problems, you could try something like http://rubyfiddle.com

Comment: The developers on my team use vim or gvim, or Sublime Text for all our coding. Only our front-end guy uses an IDE, and that's for his PHP code. Everything else we do is using a regular text editor. We develop for Linux hosts, using Mac OS systems.